# footnote inside a tested string

Tags: footnotes, strings, xstring, parsing

I would like to create a footnote within a command that tests the parent string (using `xstring`), such as:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\lymessage}{This is my\footnote{footnote text} message.}

\IfEndWith{\lymessage}{message}{It might be true.}{It is definitely false.}

\end{document}
```

I know that footnotes are fragile in general, but every variation of this I've tried has failed to compile. If I take the footnote out, it works like a charm.

I've searched for answers across the internet and haven't found this exact case/issue brought up anywhere, and unfortunately the couple of workarounds for other slightly related cases haven't been applicable to this.

Thanks in advance for any help! I'll follow-up if I happen to find a solution myself.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Probably looking for `\expandarg` in the doc of `xstring` would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard setting of `xstring` is `\fullexpandarg`; depending on how you need to use it, you can go

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\noexpandarg % don't do full expansion in `purple' arguments

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\lymessage}{This is my\footnote{footnote text} message.}

\expandafter\IfEndWith\expandafter{\lymessage}{message}{It might be true.}{It is definitely false.}

\end{document}
```

With `\noexpandarg` the arguments that in the documentation (section 3.1.1) are printed in purple color are not subject to expansion. In order to expand `\lymessage` (once), we need `\expandafter`.

Otherwise you can go with `\expandarg` that does a single expansion step on the first token in each “purple” argument.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\expandarg % expand just once the `purple' arguments

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\lymessage}{This is my\footnote{footnote text} message.}

\IfEndWith{\lymessage}{message}{It might be true.}{It is definitely false.}

\end{document}
```

Or, if you elsewhere need `\fullexpandarg`, you can disable the feature locally:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\lymessage}{This is my\footnote{footnote text} message.}

\saveexpandmode\expandarg
\IfEndWith{\lymessage}{message}{It might be true.}{It is definitely false.}
\restoreexpandmode

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could this be extended to test the argument in a convenience command? Such as `\newcommand{\testmymessage}[1]\expandafter\IfEndWith\expandafter{#1}{message.}{It might be true.}{It is definitely false.}` ? So that one could just `\testmymessage{\lymessage}`, `\testmymessage{Another message.}`, etc.

Comment: @JefferyShivers Did you try it?

Comment: I had tried it without success, but the problem at that point ended up being something else new. So ultimately yes - the first suggestion works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\lymessage}{This is my\footnote{footnote text} message.}

\begingroup
\def\footnote#1{}%
\IfEndWith{\lymessage}{message}{It might be true.}{It is definitely false.}%
\endgroup

\lymessage

\end{document}
```